# Why read.zoo gives index as dates when times are available

Tags: r, zoo, posixct

I'm trying to understand my difficulties in the past with inputting zoo objects. The following two uses of read.zoo give different results despite the default argument for tz supposedly being "" and that is the only difference between the two read.zoo calls:

```
Lines <- "2013-11-25 12:41:21         2 
2013-11-25 12:41:22.25      2 
2013-11-25 12:41:22.75      75 
2013-11-25 12:41:24.22      3 
2013-11-25 12:41:25.22      1 
2013-11-25 12:41:26.22      1"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2)

> dput(z)
structure(c(2L, 2L, 75L, 3L, 1L, 1L), index = structure(c(16034, 
16034, 16034, 16034, 16034, 16034), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2, tz="")
> dput(z)
structure(c(2L, 2L, 75L, 3L, 1L, 1L), index = structure(c(1385412081, 
1385412082.25, 1385412082.75, 1385412084.22, 1385412085.22, 1385412086.22
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), class = "zoo")
>
```

Comment: don't you get a warning in the first example?

Comment: I do get a warning. It seemed rather tangential to the matter at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectively, the default index class is `"Date"` unless `tz` is used in which case the default is `"POSIXct"`.  Thus the first example in the question gives `"Date"` class since that is the default and the second `"POSIXct"` since `tz` was specified.

If you want to specify the class without making use of these defaults then to be explicit use the `FUN` argument:

```
read.zoo(...whatever..., FUN = as.Date)
read.zoo(...whatever..., FUN = as.POSIXct) # might need FUN=paste,FUN2=as.POSIXct
read.zoo(...whatever..., FUN = as.yearmon)
# etc.
```

The `FUN` argument can also take a custom function as shown in the examples in the package.

Note that it always assumes standard formats (e.g. `"%Y-%m-%d"` in the case of `"Date"` class) if no format is specified and never tries to automatically determine the format.

The way it works is explained in detail in `?read.zoo` and there are many examples in `?read.zoo` (there are 78 lines of code in the examples section) as well as in  an entire vignette (one of six vignettes) dedicated just to `read.zoo`" : [Reading Data in zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html).

**Added** Have expanded the above.  Also, in the development version of zoo available [here](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/?group_id=18) the heuristic has been improved and with that improvement the first example in the question does recognize the date/times and chooses POSIXct.  Also some clarification of the simple heuristic has been added to the `read.zoo` help file so that the many examples provided do not have to be relied upon as much.

Here are some examples.  Note that the heuristic referred to is a heuristic to determine the *class* of the time index only.  It can only identify `"numeric"`, `"Date"` and `"POSIXct"` classes.  The heuristic cannot identify other classes (although you can specify them yourself using `FUN=`).  Also the heuristic does not identify formats.  If the format is not provided using `format=` or implicitly through `FUN=` then standard format is assumed, e.g. `"%Y-%m-%d"` in the case of `"Date"`.

```
Lines <- "2013-11-25 12:41:21  2 
2013-12-25 12:41:22.25      3 
2013-12-26 12:41:22.75      8"

# explicit.  Uses POSIXct.
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2, FUN = paste, FUN2 = as.POSIXct) 

# tz implies POSIXct
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2, tz = "")

# heuristic: Date now; devel ver uses POSIXct
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2) 


Lines <- "2013-11-251  2 
2013-12-25 3 
2013-12-26 8"

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, FUN = as.Date) # explicit.  Uses Date.
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, format = "%Y-%m-%d") # format & no tz implies Date
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines) # heuristic: Date
```

**Note:**

(1) In general, its safer to be explicit by using `FUN` or by using `tz` and/or `format` as opposed to relying on the heuristic.  If you are explicit by using `FUN` or semi-explicit by using `tz` and/or `format` then there is no change between the current and the development versions of `read.zoo`.

(2) Its safer to rely on the documentation rather than the internals as the internals can change without warning and in fact have changed in the development version.  If you really want to look at the code despite this then the key statement that selects the class of the index if `FUN` is not explicitly defined is the `if (is.null(FUN)) ...` statement in the `read.zoo` source.

(3) I recommend using `read.zoo` as being easier, direct and compact rather than workarounds such as `read.table` followed by `zoo`.  I have been using `read.zoo` for years as have many others and it seems pretty solid to me but if anyone finds specific problems with `read.zoo` or with the documentation (always possible since there is quite a bit of it) they can always be reported.  Even though the package has been around for years improvements are still being made.

Comment: The help page says 1) POSIXct if tz is present, 2) Date if format is present and 3) "heuristics" if neither is present. So why aren't the heuristics better given that tz is presumed to be "" and a two column spec was given?

Comment: The function to look at then is processFUN?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Oh, you mean the *exact same lines of code* I quote in my answer. Guess you either got out of bed the wrong side this morning or are really touchy about your documentation. Clearly my answer was so terribly bad for suggesting, oh, no, wait...

Comment: Yes, and I'm now wondering why in the case of a two-column index (with default value for tx) there is not an effort to use `toDefault`? It seems to be designed for this purpose, and as far as I can tell, it is not being called.

Answer (score 9):

The answer (of course) is in the sources for `read.zoo()`, wherein there is:

```
....
ix <- if (missing(format) || is.null(format)) {
    if (missing(tz) || is.null(tz)) 
        processFUN(ix)
    else processFUN(ix, tz = tz)
}
else {
    if (missing(tz) || is.null(tz)) 
        processFUN(ix, format = format)
    else processFUN(ix, format = format, tz = tz)
}
....
```

Even though the *default* for `tz` is `""`, in your first case `tz` is considered missing (by `missing()`) and hence `processFUN(ix)` is used. When you set `tz = ""`, it is no longer missing and hence you get `processFUN(ix, tz = tz)`.

Without looking at the details of `read.zoo()` this could possibly be handled better by having `tz = NULL` or `tz` (no default) in the arguments and then in the code, if `tz` needs to be set to `""` for some reason, do:

```
if (missing(tz) || is.null(tz)) {
    tz <- ""
}
```

or perhaps this is not even needed if all the is required is to avoid the confusion about the two different calls?

Comment: Oh come on Gabor, seriously. -1 for showing in the code *why* this happens!? Now you're just being petty. Can you explain what is factually wrong about my answer? If so I'll gladly delete it. I was just about to add pointers to the documentation but saw that you'd already done this so didn't see the need. Just because it is extensively documented doesn't mean than a seasoned R user like David will spot the pointers but I'm sure he could have worked out the issue from the code.

Comment: Arrrgh. Why is tz="" considered missing?  It should be a length 1 character vector.

Comment: @BondedDust From `?missing` "‘missing’ can be used to test whether a value was specified as an argument to a function." You didn't specify `tz` as an argument in the function call.

Comment: Given the extensitve documentation which it seems no one is reading I don't think its appropriate to claim that you need to read the source.

Comment: Did we *really* need three answers and a dozen comments to get you to consider reading the docs?

Comment: I didn't say you *needed* to, @G.Grothendieck, all I said was that the cause at the R-level of the behaviour noted in the question is easily discernable from the sources if you debug and step through. And to push back on your suggestion that one only needs to read the documentation; not all documentation is correct or up-to-date or without bugs. If you really want to know what is happening, reading the source will tell you exactly what is happening. I still don't know why you feel a -1 is appropriate given the [so] norms!? What is  factually wrong or unhelpful about my answer?

Comment: @BondedDust Sorry, I didn't mean to be terse in that comment; I meant that `tz` is considered missing because that is the semantics of the `missing()` operator. You did ask why and I explained why and pointed you to the place to look for more.

Comment: No cause for apology. You caused me to better understand `missing()`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Now you are just being obtuse. Go away.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your use of `read.zoo` tripped you up.  Here is what I did:

```
library(zoo)
tt <- read.table(text=Lines)
z <- zoo(as.integer(tt[,3]), order.by=as.POSIXct(paste(tt[,1], tt[,2])))
```

Now `z` is a proper zoo object:

```
R> z
2013-11-25 12:41:21.00 2013-11-25 12:41:22.25 2013-11-25 12:41:22.75 
                     2                      2                     75  
2013-11-25 12:41:24.22 2013-11-25 12:41:25.22 2013-11-25 12:41:26.22 
                     3                      1                      1 
R> class(z)
[1] "zoo"
R> class(index(z))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
R>
```

And by making sure I used a `POSIXct` object for the index, I am in fact getting a `POSIXct` object back.

Comment: Well, `something` tripped me up but I was not asking for an alternate set of parameters but rather an explanation why the apparently identical set of parameters leads to different results.

Comment: Both your approaches deploy `read.zoo()`. I have used `xts` and `zoo` extensively for many years, yet I never quite liked `read.zoo()` for these very reason.  I showed you how to avoid the issue by using a very standard direct `zoo()` constructor -- which is what I do (or rather, `xts()`) all the time. YMMV.

Comment: I suppose your code may be useful, but it's not answer the narrow question I posed. My question was prompted by seeing an answer from @GGrothendeick that used this form. And then I read the help page or read.zoo where the 'tz' default is listed as "". So why does leaving off the 'tz' parameter lead to Dates rather than datetimes?

Comment: With that attitude I will certainly not become more likely to use, or, gosh, recommend `read.zoo()`.  But thanks anyway for providing 'Exhibit 1' of how not to behave on SO.

Comment: @BondedDust: To me, it appears to be a clear and simple bug, oh, wait, let me call it 'misfeature' before Gabor sends a drone my way. Which is why a) I avoid the function and b) I showed you a simple and straightforward way to avoid it. But as I just wasted enough time on this I'll simply delete the answer now.

Comment: Of course it has been around for years. But I have also avoided _this function_ for years while diligently recommending zoo (and xts) and its vignettes.  Have a look at the brand new parsedate package.  Dealing with dates is *hard* so doing hidden fancy like read.zoo() does is a bad idea from the start. At least in my book.

Comment: More attitude on your behalf, so I am done here. Rest assured that I did not suggest that you replace your code with parsedate; I merely mentioned it to say that dates, are, well, complicated.  Which is pretty much what I said one comment ago.